# How should a CSS Grid layout be re-organized/re-distribuited at a media query breakpoints?

Tags: html, css, responsive, css-grid, breakpoints

I have made up a grid layout that consists of 3 columns wide and 3 rows tall:

```
.home-works {
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr 2fr;
    grid-template-rows: 2fr 4fr 4fr;

    grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

This is giving me zero problems at desktop view, but what I need to follow up with, now, is when the view port breaks, at the moment I'm working with a `max-width:768px` rule. So, right now, once the view port breaks to that max-width, any CSS Grid command doesn't seem to have an effect or a change. I have tried using `grid-row`  or `grid-row-start` `grid-column` or `grid-row-start` but no luck.

This is my HTML for the layout:

```
<div class="home-works">
                <div class="head">
                    <h1>Let's stay connected!</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-menu">
                        <img class="image-home" src="img/profile-picture.png" width="50%">
                    <ul>
                        <li>home</li>
                        <li>about</li>
                        <li>contact</li>
                        <li>downloads</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="main-content">
                        <p>This is my website and I call it, the <em>"glassless window"</em>
                            Why? Because using the frame on your device (mobile, desktop or laptop) 
                            we are allowed to establish a connection thus enabling me to show you my
                            up and coming projects. </p>
                </div>
                        <div class="caption-object">
                                <p>I really wish you could <a class="drop-a-line-link" href="#">drop me a line</a> somewhere
                                    in the future!</p>
                        </div>
            </div>
```

And this is the CSS for the distribution:

```
.head {
    grid-column: 1 / 4;
    text-align: center;
}

.col-menu {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.main-content {
    grid-column: 2 / 4;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.caption-object {
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    grid-row: 3;
}
```

This is my first time going about media queries and CSS Grid, meaning this is the first time i input a grid command inside a media query rule set. I checked to see if this would happen too if I wanted to change the `background-color: plum;` and it did worked. I know about `repeat(minmax())` but honestly I wouldn't know how to properly achieve the same look or if it would have the same 'layout design' because then I'd have to delete the grid row's and column's placement?  Like I said this is my first time ever using CSS Grid with media queries, I have attached some [pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4FuR.jpg), thanks!

Initially I decided not to include it because nothing had seemed to be working so I didn't have a reason to include.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav-items {
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .navbar {
        height: 200px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .footer-link {
        align-self: center;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .main-container {
        flex-flow: column wrap;
        margin: 0 10px;
    }
    .drop-a-line-link {
        text-decoration: underline wavy;
    }

  }
```

Media Query

Comment: I don't see any media-queries in your CSS.

Comment: it's there now.

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question this is what I did and its available on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Grid_Template_Areas), have to check "Redefining the grid using media queries" topic.

To reorganize a CSS Grid layout one must set up the media query rule (which in this case I had it different than on MDN archives but somehow still worked) and in there I had to reassign my `grid-template-areas`, which was *also* another thing I lacked, I was NOT using grid-areas, I had stuff like `grid-row` or `grid-columns`. Apparently this seems to be a huge factor that comes to play when we are inside our Media Query code. One thing that they do note as important, when working with **grid-areas** is that one should assign them, outside of any Media Query commands, to cover just one "row" or one "column", I guess depends on your current `grid-auto-flow` command, which at default is set as *row* while defining the columns and rows

So, mine is looking like this:

```
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: minmax(350px, auto);
    grid-template-areas: 
    "header"
    "menu"
    "main"
    "caption";
```

Since I had not defined any areas on my previous grid I would never have gotten it to work the way I intended for it to behave. Well, and then once in the ***MQ***, you assign the grid as best you can, but first, you need to use `grid-template-areas` to *re-assign* the areas, and as well as your columns, using `grid-template-columns`, this depends on your layout and item sizes or basically it depends on the idea that you had for the grid.

So my Media Query code ended up looking like this:

```
@media (min-width: 500px) {
    .home-works {
        grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr 2fr;

        grid-template-areas: 
        "header header menu"
        ".      main main"
        ". .    caption";
    }
}

@media (min-width:700px) {
    .home-works {
        grid-template-areas:
        "header header header"
        "menu main main"
        ". .  caption";
    }
}
```

Important: the "." are "white-space", or "negative space" or "empty cells".